# Creating a view out of other views in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I'm attempting to create a view which would be composed out of several other views.
From what i've been able to find Prism supports this in Silverlight and WPF.
I'm however using WinRT and haven't been able to find any way to achieve the same thing.

Does anyone have a suggestion in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean specifically? You can put multiple `UserControls` in one and have a combined view. Are you looking for the Prism way to do it specifically? Have you checked whether [Prism for WinRT](https://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/) supports it?

Comment: I was attempting to achieve something i learned while creating websites which is basically creating several Html pages and then combining those to create a view (which would enable me to reuse certain pieces of Html) However i spoke to my colleague and he showed me some examples for the Windows 8 way of doing this. Turns out all i needed was to change my way of thinking and start using Hub pages.

Comment: If you find it useful to share with other people - please elaborate on the question and then either answer it yourself or let other people answer it. Otherwise - I'd suggest closing the question.

Comment: I wanted to create a UI where the selection made by a user would fill a content portion of the screen. However i was thinking with Web design logic which would have you create several views and then inject these whenever needed. With WinRt there is the HubPage which achieves this using a ListView and HubGrid.
Hope this helps anyone that like me switches from Web to Windows 8 apps